# What is the most elegant way to do screen scraping in node.js?

Tags: node.js, screen-scraping

I'm in the process of hacking together a web app which uses extensive screen scraping in node.js. I feel like I'm fighting against the current at every corner. There must be an easier way to do this. Most notably, two things are irritating:

1. Cookie propagation. I can pull the 'set-cookie' array out of the response headers, but performing string operations to parse the cookies out of the array feels extremely hackish.
2. Redirect following. I want each request to follow through redirects when a 302 status code is returned.

I came across two things which *looked* useful, but I couldn't use in the end:

- http://zombie.labnotes.org/, but it doesn't have HTTPS support, so I can't use it.
- http://www.phantomjs.org/, but couldn't use it because it doesn't (appear to) integrate with node.js. It's also pretty heavyweight for what I'm doing.

Are there any JavaScript screenscraping-esque libraries which propagate cookies, follow redirects, and support HTTPS? Any pointers on how to make this easier?

Comment: After trying Zombie and every other headless browser under the sun, I ended up using node in conjunction with phantomjs and it worked beautifully. You use the spawn method in node and catch the responses from phantom. It is the only javascript based solution I found that worked with cookies, redirects, login sessions, and anything with advanced javascript. I will make a blog post on it soon and come back and comment.

Answer (score 4):

i actually have a scraper library now https://github.com/mikeal/spider it's quite nice, you can use jquery and routes.

feedback is welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

You may want to check out https://github.com/mikeal/request from mikeal, I just spoke to him the chatroom and he says that it does not handle cookies at the moment but you can write a submodule to handle these for you in the meantime.

in regards to redirect it handles beautifully :)

Comment: Cookie support is the main thing I'm looking for. Is there any support in node.js (or an npm package) which handles the parsing of the 'set-cookie' array, and outputs an appropriate header Cookie entry?

Comment: i just added cookie support :)

Comment: @mikeal, Thanks for the update, @Mike - Reinstall the request package via npm or get directly from Github, either way,  update and view docs.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out someone made a phantomjs module for node.js:

https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node

While phantom is fairly heavy, it also supports SSL, cookies, and everything else a typical browser supports (since it is a webkit browser, after all).

Give it a shot, it may be exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: You might have to use it with an older version of Phantom.js. Here is a tutorial: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/web-scraping-with-node-js/