# Scrape data generated by javascript on server-side(from webpages)?

Tags: javascript, html, screen-scraping, web-scraping

I need to get [Estate Agents Name],[Estate Licence Number] and it's [Reg No. and Salesperson]s from http://www.cea.gov.sg/cea/app/newimplpublicregister/view.jspa?licNo=L3006467E
where licNo have thousands of different variable and form thousands of URLs.
And the final outcome must be in excel format.
Note: Some of them have pagenation like:  http://www.cea.gov.sg/cea/app/newimplpublicregister/view.jspa?licNo=L3002163I

Are there any ways i can scrape the data i need?(including methods where outcome not in excel format)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441265/what-is-the-most-elegant-way-to-do-screen-scraping-in-node-js

Comment: I tried using watir and php.unfortunately,office network seem to be banned or configured something so i cant install properly to use watir and php.Now I plan to try javascript or vba.

Comment: By the way,my question missing the source that is all the links are from http://www.cea.gov.sg/cea/app/newimplpublicregister/publicregister.jspa                                                                  This add the difficulty because first need to click by alphabetically.second,each alphabet has list of links and after click each link need to go back the list and click the subsequent link.And finally,the data and its hyperlink to be get is not from the html source directly,it come from javascript function mean need to use dom or dom-supported tool.Oh,also some of them have pagenation.

Comment: you may try irobot.  check out their forum here: http://irobotsoft.org/bb/YaBB.pl

Comment: If the data is produced via javascript, try https://snapsearch.io/ I built it to help JS sites be crawlable by search engines.